# Xampp & Apache: Alias 'access denied'

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, xampp, alias

I just installed Xampp on my Arch Linux system. What i want to do now:

My PHP working directory is located in my home-folder (at */home/luke/PHP*). I want Apache to access those files two, so i followed the [Xampp Installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xampp#Hosting_files_outside_the_htdocs_directory) on the Arch Linux Wiki and created an Alias for this Directory.
This is what my httpd.conf (the Alias part) looks like:

```
Alias /PHP /home/luke/PHP
<directory /home/luke/PHP>
    AllowOverride FileInfo Limit Options Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</directory>
```

After that, i changed the permissions for the *home/luke/PHP*-folder to 777 (using chmod). I restarted Xampp and got a 403 when i tried to navigate into *http://localhost/PHP*

The Apache-Server runs under the *http*-User (which exists) and the *http*-Group. So, i added the *http*-User in my Group (the group *luke* from my user, using the chown-tool). I restarted the Server, same error.

Here is (a part from) the error_log-file:

```
[Sun Apr 24 18:05:37 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Keine Berechtigung: access to /PHP/ denied
[Sun Apr 24 18:10:30 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Keine Berechtigung: access to /PHP/ denied
[Sun Apr 24 18:10:30 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Keine Berechtigung: access to /PHP/ denied
```

So, the Alias I created should work, but what do I need to do to make my */home/luke/PHP*-folder accessible to the Apache Server?

I also tried to create a Symlink in the *htdocs*-folder, but that didn't work neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by configuring the Alias like shown above, but setting the Apache's user to my user ("luke") and leaving the Group out:

```
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
User luke
#Group http
```

After that I changed the owner of the `htdocs`- and the `PHP`-Directory to my user (luke) and restarted LAMPP.

Now everything works fine. Also thanks to Pascal MARTIN and hornetbzz!

Answer (score 2):

Apache needs to be able to :

- Read from your /home/luke/PHP directory -- you already allowed that, aparently
- Traverse the directories which are parents of that directory.

Typically, you'll have to give the execution permission to others *(which means they'll be able to traverse that directory, to go to its children)*, on your home directory :

```
chmod o+x /home/luke
```

Of course *(especially in a multi-user environment)*, you'll then have to make sure that other users cannot access your other directories and files -- typically by removing all privileges that `group` and `other` could have on directories/files under your home directory.

Comment: I changed the execution-permission like you showed, still Apache won't open the files in the PHP-folder.

Comment: @Lukas Knuth : you might have to change permissions recursively for both files and directories like:  find /home/luke -type f chmod 644 {} \; find /home/luke -type d chmod 755 {} \; and make sure they belong to the apache user. Assuming the apache user and group is set to "nobody" within your apache config file and existing on your system: chown -R nobody:nobody /home/luke

Comment: Sorry for getting back on this just now, but I was in holiday without my machine ;). Apache is running under the "http"-User and Group. If I change the owner of my 'PHP'-Directory (using chown) i can't write the files in there. I thought, setting the folders mode to 777, so anyone can write in it would fix that...

Comment: "Traverse the directories which are parents of that directory": That's the clue to this error. It has been very hard to find a correct answer. Sure chmod must be recursive! Thank you.